# Is there a way to extend the Solidity compiler to generate byte code for a new instruction?

Tags: cryptography, llvm, ethereum, solidity, evm

If you wanted to extend Solidity to generate code for a new instruction, how would you go about this? Is there some work done with something like LLVM?